# Is there an easier way to declare a lambda as a variable in java similar to that of Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

### here's how lambdas are in kotlin -

```kotlin
val myLambda: (Int, Int) -> Unit = { a, b ->
    Log.d(TAG, "sum value = ${a + b}")
}
myLambda(1, 2)//running the lambda
```

### In java, I found these two methods to do the same.

> Here, I can't have the runnable take a parameter.

```java
// runnable method
Runnable runnable = () -> {
    System.out.println("x");
};
runnable.run();
```

> The issue with this method is I would have to declare multiple interfaces for different types

```java
// interface method
Finder finder = (s1, s2) -> s1.indexOf(s2);
System.out.println(finder.find("1234", "23"));

public interface Finder {
    public int find(String s1, String s2);
}
```

So, the question I have is whether there is an easier way to implement lambda in java better that both of these.
Note - I'm new to java.

Comment: There is a builtin `ToIntBiFunction` interface that you use, without creating your `Finder` type, if that's what you mean by "easier".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to Kotlin, Java isn't a *Functional* programming language, it's *Object-oriented* and in addition has a moderate subset of functional features. On the other hand, Kotlin fully supports both Functional and Object-oriented paradigm.

In Kotlin, we can define a function, for instance like this:

```kotlin
val printSquare = { i: Int -> println(i * i) }
```

And its type would be successfully inferred, the part on the right would be recognized as being of a **function type**. Kotlin would know that it has operator `invoke()` which can be used implicitly or explicitly `printSquare.invoke(10)`.

Conversely, in Java something like that would not compile:

```
var printSquare = (int i) -> System.out.println(i * i); // compiler would not be able to infer the type `printSquare` becuase lambda expression by itself has no type
```

In Java, there's no **function types**. Instead, we have a notion of a **functional interface**.

*Functional interface* - is an interface which declares a single `abstract` method (it might also have a bunch of `static` and `default` methods, but `abstract` method should be only one). And every *lambda expression* or *method reference* should conform to a particular functional interface, i.e. they have **no** type by itself, they have to provide an implementation to the interface which would be the *target type* of lambda (or method reference).

To make the definition of `printSquare` lambda shown above compile, we to provide the type (which should be a functional interface) and target type of the lambda would be inferred from the assignment context:

```
IntConsumer printSquare = i -> System.out.println(i * i);
```

<sub>*For more information on the [type inference in Java, see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)*</sub>

Possible ways to interact with *Java 8 function* would depend on its *target type*. On `printSquare` we can invoke `accept()` and `andThen()` (`andThen` is a default method). With `Runnable` we would have only `run` at our disposal.

So the key point is that there are no *functional types* in Java, and in order to define a Java 8 function either as lambda or method reference we need either:

- Define our own *functional interface* which would be a target type for the lambda;
- Use existing *functional interface* from JDK, some kind of library, or framework.

The following Kotlin function:

```
val myLambda: (Int, Int) -> Unit = { a, b ->
    Log.d(TAG, "sum value = ${a + b}")
}
```

can be translated into Java as a [*BiConsumer*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html):

```
BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> myLambda = (a, b) -> Log.d(TAG, "sum value = " + (a + b));
```

> The issue with this method is I would have to declare multiple interfaces for different types

Well, it's actually rarely the case when you need to declare a functional interface. Only in the package [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html) there are over `40`functional interfaces at your disposal. And also there are lots and lots of them in other parts of the JDK, the most common are `Comparator`, `Runnable`, `Callable`, etc.

And there are numerous functional interfaces provided by frameworks. Because the ability to implement some functionality with a single line of code makes a life a bit easier, and because some interfaces naturally became lean when their designers respect the [*Interface segregation principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Remember that any interface, even it has been designed prior to Java 8, if it has exactly one abstract method is a *functional interface*, and therefore eligible to be implemented using lambda.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Java does not have function types built into the language.  You must have an interface for every lambda you define.

...or you can use the [built-in ones](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html), which are sufficient for many use cases.  This, for example, might be a `ToIntBiFunction<String, String>`.

Comment: Louis, I find the way you've worded this confusing.  The answer is perfectly correct, of course, but first you say there are no _"... function types built into the language ..."_, then you invite the OP to use _"...the built-in ones [function types] ..."_.  For many novices, the distinction between _"built into the language"_ and _"provided in the JDK"_ isn't clear; and therefore, it might seem like you've contradicted yourself.  I feel like this answer would be much better if you could provide clarification around this point.

Comment: He means "...the built in [interfaces]" not "...the built in [function types]". Although it is slightly ambiguous

Answer (score -1):

Since Java 8, there is the Generic Function interface. It allows you to store lambda functions.